# Not use Django static files

Tags: javascript, django

I am quite new to Django, and I hope my question is not too silly. I am currently running my project locally, and each time I do an API call with the browser, I see the server log something similar:

```
my_table    | [08/Jan/2023 20:20:42] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
my_table    | [08/Jan/2023 20:20:42] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
my_table    | [08/Jan/2023 20:20:42] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
my_table    | [08/Jan/2023 20:20:42] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/csrf.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
my_table    | [08/Jan/2023 20:20:42] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
my_table    | [08/Jan/2023 20:20:42] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/default.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
my_table    | [08/Jan/2023 20:20:42] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/prettify-min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

There are a tons of static files that are served via the API. If I do the same with Postman or similar, here is the log:

```
my_table    | [08/Jan/2023 20:25:12] "GET /api/v1/category/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

It looks like it only sends the response I wanted, via JSON or whatever. I was wandering if there is a way to prevent Django from serving static files at all, since I will only use the Rest Framework, or maybe gRPC in the future, but never static files. I tried to delete the static file constant from settings, and then nothing worked anymore, so I was wandering if there is something I need to do in order to achieve this goal. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple. You go to the installed APPS,and you will find something like:

```
BASE_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Delete the one with `django.contrib.staticfiles`, and then you can delete also the static files root variables